# MySQL - Why are there three root users with different hosts?

Tags: mysql

I'd love to know why when you first install MySQL on a server there are three `root` users entered into the users table each with different host addresses. One with `localhost` one with `127.0.0.1` and one with `::1` (for IPv6).

I don't really understand why all three are necessary. Will it enhance security to delete the `root@localhost` & `root@::1` and only leave `root@127.0.0.1` with access? Would that be a good thing to do or not? If not, what are the other host addresses used for?

NB: I'm running MySQL on an ubuntu based server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as MySQL is concerned a connection from 127.0.0.1 is different from a connection from ::1 so if you want to access the server from either protocol you need to allow it. The localhost entry is there to allow connections via a socket connection rather than a tcp connection so

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u user -p
mysql -h ::1 -u user -p
mysql -h localhost -u user -p
```

are all different connections. Using

```
mysql -h localhost  -u user -p -e 'show full processlist\G;'
...
User: user
Host: localhost
...
```

and

```
mysql -h localhost  --protocol=tcp -u user -p -e 'show full processlist\G;'
...
User: user
Host: localhost:60249
...
```

Note the port number 60249 which shows it's a TCP connection.